# Find nearest indexes of multiple values

Tags: python

I am trying find the nearest index range of multiple values in a column. I added a minimal working code of python as follows. My data range is bigger than in this given example. It is more than 3000 rows. Following is working as I expected, but process time takes little longer, approximately 50-60 seconds.

How can I reduce this time? Is there different approach for this case?

**Not:** My model X and Y vals are in 'list' and 'vals' columns,
obversed X vals are in 'obser' column
trying to get index no and calculated Y vals with **FindNearest** function

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt

def FindNearest(Table, Value):
    idx = Table['list'].sub(Value).abs().idxmin()       # find nearest index no
    row_nrst = Table.loc[idx]                   # get all vals at nearest

    # is value big (-1) or small (+1) from nearest, to decide second nearest val
    updwn = -1 if Value > row_nrst['list'] else 1

    # get model vals that value is between of them
    lst1, lval1 = row_nrst[['list', 'vals']]
    lst2, lval2 = Table.loc[idx+updwn, ['list', 'vals']]

    #calculate observed Y val
    rvals = lval1 + (lval2-lval1)*(Value-lst1)/(lst2-lst1)

    return pd.Series([idx, rvals])



start = dt.now()

aa = np.matrix([
    [  15,   14,  13,  12,   11,   10,   9,    8],              # model X vals
    [ 100.5, 94.5, 88.5, 66.5, 74.5, 91.5, 105.5, 120.5],       # model Y vals
    [12.3, 14.6, 8.7, 13.5, 14.2, 9.4, 11.3, 11.5],             # observed X vals
    [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],                           # index of model X vals
    [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]                            # calculalted observed Y vals
]).transpose()

tbl = pd.DataFrame(aa, columns=['list', 'vals', 'obser', 'ids', 'obsval'])

# finding process is peformed with **apply** function of Pandas library
tbl[['ids', 'obsval']] = tbl.apply(lambda x: FindNearest(tbl, x['obser']), axis=1)

elapsed = dt.now() - start

print(tbl)

print('Elapsed time :%2.3Fsn'%(elapsed.total_seconds()))
```

Comment: I think you're looking for the closest obser. Rather than searching the entire list many times, perhaps you could create a new, temporary column, which is the absolute value of the each column minus the Value? Then sort ascending based on the abs value and return the smallest.

Comment: I am trying to find the nearest value of model X vals for each element of observed X vals. It is not suitable for this case to make a single temproray column to search closest.

Comment: Why is this not suitable? This seems like the "better approach" you asked for.

Comment: How should we create this column? Is it possible to show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a method that takes one pass through to the data to create the column with the closest index.

Here's your original code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
aa = np.matrix([
    [  15,   14,  13,  12,   11,   10,   9,    8],              # model X vals
    [ 100.5, 94.5, 88.5, 66.5, 74.5, 91.5, 105.5, 120.5],       # model Y vals
    [12.3, 14.6, 8.7, 13.5, 14.2, 9.4, 11.3, 11.5],             # observed X vals
    [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],                           # index of model X vals
    [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]                            # calculated observed Y vals
]).transpose()

tbl = pd.DataFrame(aa, columns=['list', 'vals', 'obser', 'ids', 'obsval'])
```

Then I added two sentinel rows to be the first row and last row.

```
bb = np.matrix([
    [  -999,   999],              # model X vals
    [ 0.0, 0.0],       # model Y vals
    [float ("-inf"), float("inf")],             # observed X vals
    [-1, -1],                           # index of model X vals
    [-1, -1]                            # calculated observed Y vals
]).transpose()
sentinel = pd.DataFrame(bb, columns=['list', 'vals', 'obser', 'ids', 'obsval'])
sentinel.head()
```

Then I created a single dataframe that combined your data with the sentinel rows, sorted.

```
df = tbl.append(sentinel, ignore_index=False)
df.sort_values('obser', inplace=True)
print (df.head(10))
```

Here are the results:

```
    list   vals  obser  ids  obsval
0 -999.0    0.0   -inf -1.0    -1.0
2   13.0   88.5    8.7 -1.0    -1.0
5   10.0   91.5    9.4 -1.0    -1.0
6    9.0  105.5   11.3 -1.0    -1.0
7    8.0  120.5   11.5 -1.0    -1.0
0   15.0  100.5   12.3 -1.0    -1.0
3   12.0   66.5   13.5 -1.0    -1.0
4   11.0   74.5   14.2 -1.0    -1.0
1   14.0   94.5   14.6 -1.0    -1.0
1  999.0    0.0    inf -1.0    -1.0
```

Finally, create three rows: prev, curr, and next. Compare the obser and pick the smaller of the two.

```
closest_idx = []

for i, row in enumerate(df[:2].itertuples()):
    if i == 0:
        print ('setting prev')
        prev = row
    if i == 1:
        print ('setting curr')
        curr = row


for i, next in enumerate(df[2:].itertuples()):
    if (next.obser - curr.obser) > (curr.obser - prev.obser):
        closer_idx = prev.Index
    else:
        closer_idx = next.Index

    print (f'for row {i}, using {closer_idx}')

    prev = curr
    curr = next

    closest_idx.append(closer_idx)

print (f'{closest_idx}')
```

This prints out the row of closest indices:

```
[5, 2, 7, 6, 7, 4, 1, 4]
```